# VS 2013 Desktop C# Automating Word 2007

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation

I've gone through the hits in the search and can find no relief.

I'm trying to populate an Avery template with data.  I've found several good examples, but they all have a hitch.

Each one begins with code like:

```
Dim objApp As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
objApp = New Word.Application()
objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open("//Path of a file to Open")
```

I add the word 2007 reference (Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library) to the project and the Word object does not exist, so the first two lines won't compile.

Am I getting the right object library for Word 2007?  It's the only version I have installed.

Am I missing dll's that might show up by re-installing Word?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this, in my opinion, is to use the primary interop assemblies provided by Microsoft. When you set a reference to the COM libraries, Visual Studio creates an interop assembly for you. Presumably, automatically generated interop assemblies won't be as clean as those generated by a developer specifically for an application.

There is information about the primary interop assemblies here:

```
 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx
```

EDIT:
Once you have set a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word interop assembly, you can reference it like this at the top of your class files:

```
 using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

Then, you can refer to it in your code like this:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open("filename to open");
```

Comment: Thanks Markus:
I see that I got a reference to an interop assembly, but the object, "word" is still not defined.

Comment: Once you include a reference to the primary interop assembly, you should be able to put "using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;" at the top of your class file. That syntax creates an alias for "Word".

In any case, after you set a using statement, you should be able to do this:

    Word.Application app = new Word.Application();

or 

    var app = new Word.Application();

Comment: I just tested that and it seems to work. Under References, you should see "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word".

Answer (score 0):

You use `C#` as the developing language (you mentioned it in the tags you've attached to the post)

But, in the code you post you use the `Visual Basic` syntax.
That's why you cannot compile the first 2 lines.

Instead of

```
Dim objApp As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
```

Use

```
 Word.Application objApp ;
 Word.Document objDoc ;
```

Put attention to locate a `;` character at the end of each line.

Comment: Sorry, yes that must haveve been confusing.  I gave up on .net and returned to my roots in Vb6, but had the same problem, until your response made me realize I hadn't added the reference to the Microsoft Word 12 object library.  I added a reference to the Word library and all is well.

TY

Edit - I just realized both you and Markus gave me virtually the same pointer that lead to successful conclusion.

How can I mark both your answers, or should I?

Comment: You can vote Markus' answer as the accepted since he was the first, and up vote mine...